# How would I plot the volume element in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions

I have this graph:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nag9x.png]

But it doesn't have a function so I can't just plugin in a function into wolfram or mathematica to plot it. I have these coordinates to make it however:

```
(1, 0, 1)  (2, 0, 1)  (1, 0, 2)  (2, 0, 2)  (1, Pi/6, 1)  (2, Pi/6, 1)  (1, Pi/6, 2)  (2, Pi/6, 2)
```

How would I enter this in wolfram or mathematica to plot it? I am trying to download the STL file for it to print it in 3D.

Comment: By "wolfram", do you mean "Wolfram | Alpha"?

Comment: Plus, `pi` is not a recognized symbol; use `Pi` instead

Comment: Yes I mean wolfram alpha or mathematica, I know wolfram alpha has a plot function where you can download 3D STL's and 3Ds files if you have a pro account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to get you started

```
RegionPlot3D[
   0 < z < 1 && 1 < Norm[{x, y}] < 2 && 1/2 < ArcTan[y, x] < 1.1, 
   {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, -1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Yellow]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this  0 < z < 1 && 1 < Norm[{x, y}] < 2 && 1/2 < ArcTan[y, x] < 1.1, I understand the rest of that code, thanks.

Comment: @Ratman2050 Take a look at the help page for `RegionPlot3D`. There are lot of example in there

Answer (score 8):

As belisarius  has shown(and I have voted for his answer) `RegionPlot3D` allows you to plot your region.
FYI:

1. Your lists of coordinates (as with all lists in Mathematica):

   ```
    coord = {{1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {1, Pi/6, 1}, {2,
    Pi/6, 1}, {1, Pi/6, 2}, {2, Pi/6, 2}};
   ```
2. You can transform  these cylindrical coordinates to cartesian coordinates:

   ```
    pts = CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", coord]
   ```
3. You need to define your region using inequalities, as per belisarius, and you can overlay your vertices to check:

   ```
   Show[RegionPlot3D[1 <= z <= 2 && 1 <= Norm[{x, y}] <= 2 && 
   0 < Arg[Complex[x, y]] < Pi/6, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotPoints -> 100], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}]]
   ```

[image]

Comment: For those who are viewing this question, I would have chosen this answer as it is more complete, but I think belisarius deserved some credit since he had the first answer. But thank you ubpdqn, this outputted the STL file very nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something I use in class to demonstrate cylindrical coordinates (sorry for the length, but it's what I have :):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{$θColor = Red, $rColor = Darker[Blue], $zColor = Brown},

  figure[P0_, 0., 0., 0.] := {
    Thick, $rColor, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}}], $zColor,
     Line[{{P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}, P0}]
    };
  figure[P0_, 0., Δθ_, 0.] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], z}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $θColor]]
    };
  figure[P0_, 0., 0., Δz_] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], s}, {s, z, z + Δz},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $zColor]]
    };
  figure[P0_, Δr_, 0., 0.] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[θ], u Sin[θ], z}, {u, r, r + Δr},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $rColor]]
    };
  figure[P0_, 0., Δθ_, Δz_] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], s}, {s, z, z + Δz}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter[$rColor]]]
    };
  figure[P0_, Δr_, 0., Δz_] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[θ], u Sin[θ], s}, {s, z, z + Δz}, {u, r, r + Δr}, 
      Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Lighter[$θColor]]
    };
  figure[P0_, Δr_, Δθ_, 0.] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], z}, {u, r, r + Δr}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Lighter[$zColor]]
    };
  figure[P0_, Δr_, Δθ_, Δz_] := {
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], s}, {s, z, z + Δz}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$rColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[θ], u Sin[θ], s}, {s, z, z + Δz}, {u, r, r + Δr}, 
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> 
       Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$θColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], z}, {u, r, r + Δr}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$zColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
    First@ParametricPlot3D[ {(r + Δr) Cos[t], (r + Δr) Sin[t], s},
      {s, z, z + Δz}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$rColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[θ + Δθ], u Sin[θ + Δθ], s},
      {s, z, z + Δz}, {u, r, r + Δr}, 
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$θColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
    First @ ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], z + Δz}, {u, r, r + Δr}, {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
      Mesh -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$zColor], Opacity[opacity]]]
    };

  Dynamic @ With[{P0 = {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], z}},
    Graphics3D[{
      {PointSize[Medium], Point[P0], 
       Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ (3 IdentityMatrix[3])], Opacity[0.3], 
       Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ (-3 IdentityMatrix[3])]}, {
       {Opacity[0.3], 
        EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[Medium], Opacity[0.3]]], 
        Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, P0[[3]]}, 
          P0, {P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}}],
        $θColor, 
        EdgeForm[
         Directive[Thickness[Medium], 
          If[Δr == 0 && Δz == 0 && Δθ == 0, Opacity[1], 
           Opacity[0.3]], $θColor]], 
        Polygon[Append[
          Table[0.3 {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, Append[Range[0, θ, 0.05], θ]}],
          {0, 0, 0}]]},
       Line[{{P0, {0, 0, P0[[3]]}}, {{P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}, {P0[[1]], 0, 0}},
         {{P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}, {0, P0[[2]], 0}}}], 
       Point[DiagonalMatrix[P0]]
       },
      figure[P0, Δr, Δθ, Δz]
      },
     SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 2, Lighting -> "Neutral"
     ]]],
 Row[{Control[{{r, 1}, 0., 2, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δr, 0., 1., ImageSize -> Small}]}, 
  Spacer[1]],
 Row[{Control[{z, 0., π, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δz, 0., π, ImageSize -> Small}]}, 
  Spacer[1]],
 Row[{Control[{θ, 0., 2 π, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δθ, 0., 2 π, 
     ImageSize -> Small}]}, Spacer[1]],
 {{opacity, 1}, 0., 1}, {{figure, figure}, None},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> {}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]